# Why Word removes the paragraph format when hitting the delete key? And how to solve it?

Tags: microsoft-word

This "bug" bothers me for years already: When using the delete key on the last line of the Word document, the format gets removed completely. See the short demo clip:

[image: word 2003 paragraph format bug]

I am using Word 2003, but this might be the case in other versions too?

Question is: How to turn off this behaviour? Prevent the format removal?

Comment: The paragraph mark is what the formatting is tied to.  When you delete it, the formatting goes with it.

Comment: The last paragraph has the same format as the previous paragraph (both Calibri 12pt). But it triggers the times new roman formatting somehow.

Comment: Sounds like as @fixer1234 states, the formatting is deleted thus returns to the default normal setting

Comment: And how to prevent this happening? How to solve the bug?

Comment: This isn't a bug, it's fundamental to the way Word works.  If you delete a paragraph mark that has formatting associated with it, the affected text will revert to the default format settings.  The only way to prevent it is to either not delete that paragraph mark, or copy the formatting from it to other paragraph marks as needed.

Comment: That's is one of the main reasons for keeping the paragraph marks visible.  It helps to identify where formatting is "stored" so that you don't accidentally remove formatting.

Answer (score 0):

One solution to your problem would be just to select the paragraph mark and formatting it as Hidden. This way you don't see the paragraph marks and you still retain your formatting. I'm sure someone can come up with a better solution, but this can be a temporary fix.